# Last child is null error when query through Dom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have DOM structure of HTML <- Body <- Div <-img , img, img . I am trying to run a mouse click even on div's last child. but it gives me null reference error.

Here is my javascript code :

```
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide"); //div id = "leftside" 
theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){..}
```

However it gives me error of

```
theLeftSide.lastChild is null
```

What i am doing wrong here.

Here's DOM
[image]

Comment: This means the element doesn't have any child element, at least when the query is executed.

Comment: No the body on-load function creates 5 image child elements before executing this query on div.

Comment: i edited and include the image of DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the element doesn't have any child element, at least when the query is executed.

> No the body on-load function creates 5 image child elements before executing this query on div.

That should be the problem. When the query and the next line are executed the target elements are not created yet. Timing matters. You can move the above snippet into your onload handler. Don't let the live representation of DOM confuse you.